# xpath get Parent of Node

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following XML (from an HP iLO)

```
<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
    <FIRMWARE_INFORMATION>
        <INDEX_1>
            <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "HP ProLiant System ROM"/>
            <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "12/14/2012"/>
        </INDEX_1>
        <INDEX_2>
            <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "HP ProLiant System ROM - Backup"/>
            <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "12/14/2012"/>
        </INDEX_2>
        <INDEX_3>
            <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "HP ProLiant System ROM Bootblock"/>
            <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "03/11/2012"/>
        </INDEX_3>
        <INDEX_4>
            <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "iLO"/>
            <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "1.13 Nov 08 2012"/>
        </INDEX_4>
        <INDEX_5>
            <FIRMWARE_NAME VALUE = "Power Management Controller Firmware"/>
            <FIRMWARE_VERSION VALUE = "3.1"/>
        </INDEX_5>
    </FIRMWARE_INFORMATION>
</GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
```

I'm using PHP SimpleXML Xpath, and I want to find out the iLO version and select the parent, however the parent is in an unknown node (because it could be in an of the INDEX nodes.

I've managed to get this far:

```
$ilover = $xml->FIRMWARE_INFORMATION->xpath("//FIRMWARE_NAME[@VALUE='iLO']");
```

That returns me the node with the iLO version it in, but I also need the node containing FIRMWARE_VERSION which is next to the selected node.

Is it possible to get either:
1. Search for my node as above, but to select the parent
2. Search for my node as above and then return the data from a different node next to my current node

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath to get parent element of `FIRMWARE_NAME` where `VALUE` attribute equals 'iLO':

```
$ilover = $xml->FIRMWARE_INFORMATION->xpath("*[FIRMWARE_NAME/@VALUE='iLO']");
```

or to return `FIRMWARE_VERSION` instead of the parent element :

```
//*[FIRMWARE_NAME/@VALUE='iLO']/FIRMWARE_VERSION
```

Comment: Can I get it to return just the value in the second query?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$ilover = $xml->FIRMWARE_INFORMATION->xpath("//FIRMWARE_NAME[@VALUE='iLO']")[0]->xpath('parent::*');
```

It will get you the parent node and you can then get both child nodes like:

```
var_dump($ilover[0]->FIRMWARE_NAME);
var_dump($ilover[0]->FIRMWARE_VERSION);
```